# How can I put three elements in the same column, with the first on top, second and third in the center of the remaining space, using Flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a container with three paragraphs. The first contains a picture. The second is the title of that picture. The third is the description of the picture.

I need the photo to be **on top** of the container and the two remaining paragraphs to be **in the middle** of the vertical space that remains, obviously the title on top of the description.

The closest to this requirements I've been able to get is having the picture on top, the title just below it (so on top of the remaining vertical space) and the description in the middle of the remaining vertical space. The CSS of this would be:

```
.flexbox-container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.flexbox-container .one-fourth {
    background-color: #1E73BE;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flexbox-container .one-fourth .image-name,
.flexbox-container .one-fourth .image-description {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.image {
    margin: 0;
}

.image-name {
    flex: 1;
}

.image-description {
    flex: auto;
}
```

Does anybody know how to modify this to achieve what I need?

**Update -** here's the html markup:

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="one-fourth">
        <p class="image"><img class="..."...></p>
        <p class="image-name"></p>
        <p class="image-description"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-fourth">
        <p class="image"><img class="..."...></p>
        <p class="image-name"></p>
        <p class="image-description"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-fourth">
        <p class="image"><img class="..."...></p>
        <p class="image-name"></p>
        <p class="image-description"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-fourth">
        <p class="image"><img class="..."...></p>
        <p class="image-name"></p>
        <p class="image-description"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="one-fourth">
        <p class="image"><img class="..."...></p>
        <p class="image-name"></p>
        <p class="image-description"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="one-fourth">
    ...and so on.
```

Comment: by "on top of the container" do you mean "aligned to the outside edge of the top border of the container" or do you mean "aligned to inside edge of the top border of the container"? I'm guessing you mean the latter, but the phrasing you used technically means the former.

Comment: Also, please include the markup (HTML) that you have for this construct.

Comment: Updated, thanks. As for your question, the latter, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible **natively** with flexbox.

You would need to wrap the "centered" items in their own element which takes up the remaining height and center the contents in that. You'd also have to give the column a defined height...*or at least a height the browser can reconcile*.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.column {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.img-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
.wrap {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, fugiat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a row

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.column {
  padding: 1em;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
.img-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
.wrap {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, fugiat.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="img-wrap">
      <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/140/100" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi ad non fuga cumque accusamus tempore obcaecati nihil reprehenderit suscipit, voluptas doloremque nostrum doloribus maxime? Possimus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Quis, veniam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't give a defined height, as pictures have different sizes, and also titles and descriptions. But the biggest problem is obviously the pictures sizes. Thanks.

Comment: Then you can't do it. If the columns don't have a height, the "remaining space" is undefined. It will work if all the columns have the *same height* which might be the case if they are flex items but the principle is the same.. . **you need a wrapper**.

Comment: I've been playing with your code and it works without a defined height, just adding a wrapper div for the two items that I need centered. So thank you very much! Did you expect it to work without a defined height?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

Just play with margin auto where you need the space to grow to make the elements centered:

```css
.flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
}
.flexbox-container .one-fourth {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 2px;
}
.image {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0px;
}
.one-fourth:nth-child(1) .image {
  height: 50px;
}
.one-fourth:nth-child(2) .image {
  height: 75px;
}
.one-fourth:nth-child(3) .image {
  height: 100px;
}
.one-fourth:nth-child(4) .image {
  height: 125px;
}
.image-name {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto 0 0 0;
}
.image-description {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: tomato;
  margin: 0 0 auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-container">
  <div class="one-fourth">
    <p class="image"></p>
    <p class="image-name"></p>
    <p class="image-description"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="one-fourth">
    <p class="image"></p>
    <p class="image-name"></p>
    <p class="image-description"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="one-fourth">
    <p class="image"></p>
    <p class="image-name"></p>
    <p class="image-description"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="one-fourth">
    <p class="image"></p>
    <p class="image-name"></p>
    <p class="image-description"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```